# Selling DIY electronics online

Tags: distributors

Ok, I have no idea if this is the best place to ask for this kind of question but I've been scattering the internet for a while to find any info regarding this:

Can we sell DIY electronics online? I'm from Canada.

Let's first define "DIY electronics":

- Power supply is bought so has all the needed regulation. We are not
  going into power supply design. DIY means to me, not having to go
  through a 10k$ certification process only for AC/DC conversions. A
  decent market supplied power supply seems safe.
- A PCB with a microcontroller/processor with all low DC voltage and signals
- 3D printed cases and accessories.
- If there is RF signals, it all comes from already approved modules bought on the market. (Because I know there is some more regulations
  regarding RF designs approval).
- A nice box for shipping.

Would there be any regulations/problems/anything I should be aware of or that I may be missing?

Please share any experience or relevant links on the subject.

Comment: This isn't really the place, but if you sell anything there will be certain certifications that are *required*. Selling a *design* that someone else procures and assembles is a different matter.

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about. The cheap arduinos I get from China don't have any trace of certifcations on them. But I think it is logic, it doesn't include a power supply. 

Let's simplify the question: what if you only have a PCB with a micro on it with a power in socket for DC 5V. DIY kits and cheap oscillators on a PCB also don't seem to provide any kind of certifications inprints.

Comment: But every AC/DC power supply brick I've ever seen, though, comes with a plethora of certifications imprints.

Comment: Take a look at Tindie.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Very sound advice!

Answer (score 4):

I can't help with Canadian regulations, but I would caution on selling internationally to EU counties (as you mentioned a web shop).

Selling practically all electronic products in/to the EU requires CE marking, and attestation of compliance with certain regulations is required in that. You can self-declare without expensive lab testing, but as you're asking here you wouldn't be competent to do so.

The most important thing to bear in mind, and this may very well be true in Canada too, is that a sub-assembly being compliant is essentially irrelevant. The regulations only care about the complete product and your particular use of compliant components can easily render the whole non-compliant.

Comment: An incredible amount of cheap products have a CE mark, while obviously non-compliant. If you are honest with what you are selling, and do not cut corners when it's about price vs safety, you'll be fine. *(insurance for legal assistance might still be a wise move)*